# New to Ubuntu, Kernel question

Tags: drivers, kernel, 14.10, compat-wireless

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm using 14.10. I have a Rosewill Wireless card, n600PCE, and it's giving me a driver for Linux Kernel 2.4 or 2.6. As I am new, these will work, right? It's not like trying to load a Windows XP driver to Windows 8, right?

Comment: Hard to know, but the 2.4 kernel is very old. Is this an old wireless card ? Please identify the card and although you can try the old drivers, it would be optimal to use one for a 3.x kernel.

Comment: It's not a new card, but it's definitely not old, it's driven by the RT5592 by RaLink.

Comment: If the driver is binary, it will work only for the *exact* kernel for which it was compiled. If it is source, chances are that it is already in the new kernel --- otherwise you can try to compile it, but it's definitely not a newbee thing ;-), and can be different from driver to driver. Didn't work with 14.10?

Comment: The 2.4 kernel is quite old, so I would beg to differ with " it's definitely not old" - those drives are ancient.

Comment: It does not detect it on 14.10, I have plugged in a WiFi adapter I know works on 14.10 and it pulls it just fine. Only problem is it's an old wireless g card. If I were to find an already compiled version of the driver from, say an ASUS version of the card, would that still work, in theory?